Two morphisms are equal if they are equal fiberwise.
Suppose $S$ is a reduced scheme and $X$, $Y$ are finite type $S$-schemes. When can we say that two morphisms $f$, $g$ $: X\longrightarrow Y$ are equal iff they are equal fiberwise, i.e. $f(s)=g(s)$, where $f(s)$ is a morphism obtained under bace-change $Spec(\kappa(s))\longrightarrow S$?
Let me provide an example of when this statement holds true. If $X=Y=Spec(R[t,t^{-1}])$, then showing above is equivalent to showing that a morphism that sends $t$ to zero for each reduction modulo $\mathfrak{p}\in Spec(R)$ sends $t$ to $0$ to begin with. The latter follows since a morphism corresponds to a polynomial $p(t)\in R[t,t^{-1}]$ and $p(t)=\sum{a_it_i}$ with $a_i \in (0)$.
I am looking for assumptions on X and Y which are as general as possible for this fibre criterion to hold true, maybe one doesn't even need to assume that they are of finite type. Thanks!

In this situation, the condition ${f=g}$ defines a locally closed subscheme $Z$ of $X$ such that $Z_s \rightarrow X_s$ is an isomorphism for every $s \in S$. Hence $Z \rightarrow X$ is a surjective immersion.
In particular, if $X$ is reduced, then $Z=X$ and $f=g$. I’m sure there has to be some other set of more “relative” sufficient conditions (maybe if $X,Y$ are smooth $S$-schemes?).
